# How to determine a streak of "perfect sets" of data?

Tags: google-sheets

I would like to be able to track a metric for some trading drills I'm doing in "sets" of typically 10 to 20 trades.  I already track winners and losers, and a "perfect set" is a set that has no losers.

Each set has a text label - Set 1, Set 2, Set 12, etc.  I can get win streaks easily enough, but I can't figure out how to get the streak of consecutive perfect sets.

I've been scouring Google, Reddit, StackExchange, and spent a lot of time with chatGPT, Claude, and Groq, but though I've gotten close a couple of times (correctly identifying perfect sets), I can't seem to get to the final result I'm after.

I've [provided a sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1f8XJK3KTterr26aJoGq1PesxxeZSOYGPgw_dwb5jVbY/edit?usp=sharing) where I've scrubbed all but the needed data, maybe someone here can point me in the right direction.  My desired result in this sample would go in the yellow cell at AG1.

Comment: Consider providing input and expected output as **plain text table** in the question. [Click here](//webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855) to create a table easily, which are **easy to copy/paste**.  Avoid sharing links like spreadsheets, which make the question [useless for others](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455) or images, which are [hard to copy](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Also, note that [your email address can also be accessed by the public](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394304), if you share Google files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this formula:

```
=LET(sets,TOCOL(UNIQUE(AA2:AA),1),
losses,BYROW(sets,LAMBDA(set,SUMIF(AA:AA,set,D:D))),
cumStreak,SCAN(0,losses,LAMBDA(a,v,IF(v=0,a+1,0))),
MAX(cumStreak))
```

To help you visualize the process, I added a picture with the "auxiliary columns" that are defined inside the formula. They AREN'T NECESSARY, they are for illustration.

With LET I'm stablishing the steps: first, I find the Unique sets - in yellow in the picture. Then I find how many losses are inside each of the sets (with BYROW and SUMIF) - in green in the picture. Then I find what's the cummulative streak of sets with 0 losses (with SCAN) - in blue. And finally, I find the maximum value, which is the Max Streak.

[image]

Comment: Very nice approach!  And quite different from any of the other approaches I tried.  Thanks for this, I can learn quite a bit as well as getting the result I was looking for!